# Error while trying to attach debugger from PTVS

Tags: python, azure, bottle, ptvs

I have created a Bottle Py website and deployed it to Azure Websites, but now I have made some changes and when I published it Site again, the site gave an internal error.  When I tried to attach debugger received below error

"Existing connection is forcefully closed by remote host"

[image]

Update:  I posted the same in PTVS Discussions and got the answer there,  possibly this might get fixed in RTM.

[https://pytools.codeplex.com/discussions/551920](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=pytools)

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable web sockets for your website in Azure management console?